# Visualizing custom geo data on WFS featurecollection

Tags: geoserver, wfs, visualisation

I have some data that I want to visualize over on an interactive map. Basically I want to highlight certain buildings based on the data that I have. My data consists of coordinates and I need to match each coordinate to a building and then highlight that building. Just to illustrate  what I want to achieve, here is a picture I drew in paint.

[image: https://ibb.co/0jM61zC]

I am getting the outline of the buildings by using the WFS GetFeature functionality from a publicly available geoserver. I was thinking that I could use the bbox parameter to match each of my coordinates with one of the buildings and then simply draw colored polygons on matching buildings. But considering I have potentially thousands of coordinate pairs this doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Could someone suggest a good way to achieve what I am looking for? I am quite new to this and have spent quite some time figuring this out, but I can't figure out the best way to do this (One idea I did have is to create my own feature layer using WFS).

Comment: If you are getting actual features that you can import to a layer, your best bet is to write a python script  to iterate over that layer and generate/color the polygons for you. Check out the Plugins/Python Console.    There are some code examples for you to get the layer and make new layers from the existing data.  I can post an example if you want to automate this a bit.

Comment: So what you are saying is I can make a script that iterates over the features that I have right now, and create a new layer that simply gives a polygon a color based on my data? Would I then also be able to serve it with a custom Geoserver through WFS?